# JQuery fullCalendar - how to know the coordinates of the event during dragging

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar library to power up my calendar application. Currently my goal is to detect somehow that the user has reached the corder of the calendar. To do this, firstly, I have to find a method to fetch the event coordinates in real time as the user keeps moving the event. Any inbuilt native way (of FullCalendar library) to do this? Or it's up to me to implement this? And if yes, how ????

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7oL15hqb/).

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: true,
    events: [{
        title: 'Some Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
        allDay: false
    }, {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 13, 0),
        allDay: false
    }],
    eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
            console.log(jsEvent.offsetX);
        },
});
```

`eventDragStart` only provides the coordinates at the start, while I need to get their changes in real time as the user keeps moving the event

Answer (score -2):

Good day here is an example for the event click where jsEvent.pageX = x...

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    //alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
    //alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' +jsEvent.pageY);
}
```